# How can I get, and re-use, the next 6 *dates* from today in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a CTE I can re-use that will hold seven *dates*. That is today and the next six days.

So, output for today (4/22/2022) should be:

```
2022-04-22
2022-04-23
2022-04-24
2022-04-25
2022-04-26
2022-04-27
2022-04-28
```

So far, I have this:

```
WITH seq AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS [idx]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [idx] + 1
    FROM seq
    WHERE [idx] < 6
)
SELECT DATEADD(dd, [idx], CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
FROM seq;
```

The problem is my SELECT is outside the WITH, so I would need to wrap this whole thing with another WITH to re-use it, for example to JOIN on it as a list of dates, and I'm not having luck getting that nested WITH to work. How else could I accomplish this?

To be clear: I'm not trying to find records in a specific table full of dates that are from the next seven days. There are plenty of easy solutions for that. I need a list of *dates* for today and the next six days, that I can re-use in other queries as a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Here's an example:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    1 as n
    ,GETDATE() as dt
  union all
  select 
    n+1
    ,DATEADD(dd,n,GETDATE()) as dt
  from cte
  where n <= 6
)
select * from cte
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63112ca15e1c5e1b1907f944234ce929)

You can create a view for reusability and simply query the view rather than using the same CTE over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a second column for the date to the CTE:

```
WITH seq AS (
    SELECT 0 AS [idx], cast(current_timestamp as date) as date
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [idx] + 1,  dateadd(dd, idx+1, cast(current_timestamp as date))
    FROM seq
    WHERE [idx] < 6
)
SELECT *
FROM seq;
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=208ecd76be2071529078f38b1735b0cd

Another option is you can "stack" CTEs, rather than nest, to avoid the second column:

```
WITH seq0 AS (
    SELECT 0 AS [idx]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [idx] + 1
    FROM seq0
    WHERE [idx] < 6
),
seq As (
    SELECT dateadd(dd, idx, cast(current_timestamp as date)) as idx
    FROM seq0
)

SELECT *
FROM seq;
```

Note how the final query only needed to reference the 2nd CTE.

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22315438e4710792f368009cc6ff6451

Answer (score 0):

Never recommend using recursion if you don't have a need for it. It's more complex and slower. I'd just use a hardcoded list of numbers, could encapsulate it in TVF if you wanted to reuse it across different stored procedures/functions. If you need to reuse it in 1 stored proc in multiple places, I'd just throw it in a temp table.

### CTE Version without Recursion

```
WITH cte_7days AS (
    SELECT theDate = CAST(DATEADD(dd,num,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS A(num)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_7days
```

### CROSS APPLY Version to Remove Need for CTE

Could use something like this as your base query, and then just add more joins below table depending on your query

```
SELECT theDate
FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS A(num)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT theDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,num,GETDATE()) AS DATE)) AS B
```

### TVF Version

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_7days()
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT theDate
    FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) AS A(num)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT theDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,num,GETDATE()) AS DATE)) AS B
)
GO
```